# Read Sony BRAVIA model over RS-232

Tags: powershell, serial-port

I am trying to write script that detect connected TV's model over serial (RS232).

It works fine with a SHARP TV, but when I connect to a SONY BRAVIA, the script returns `p p` instead of `FW-65XE8501`.

```
[Byte[]] $request = 0x8c,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x01,0x8f

$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.Write($request, 0, $request.Count)

Start-Sleep -s 2

$readable = $port.BytesToRead
$response = $port.ReadExistings()

Write-Host $readable # 3
Write-Host $response # p p

$port.Close()
```

Comment: Why you're expecting that this will work? Are there some specifications about accessing this TV over a serial port?

Comment: @montonero I find this code at https://support.justaddpower.com/kb/article/22-sony-rs232-control/
Unfortunatelly can't google more info :(

Comment: I guess you could try to start from here https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/integrate/rs-232c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have an answer: current software don't provide this information, only respond **p t** or **p p**...